# When and by whom was “coronnial” coined?

Tags: word-usage, neologisms

The Cambridge Dictionary blog posted on May 11th, 2020 a new word:

***[Coronnial](http://Westend61%20/%20Getty%20coronnial%20noun%20[C]%20UK%20/k%C9%99%CB%88r%C9%99%CA%8A.ni.%C9%99l/%20US%20/k%C9%99%CB%88ro%CA%8A.ni.%C9%99l/%20someone%20who%20was%20born%20around%20the%20time%20of%20the%20covid-19%20pandemic%20%20There%E2%80%99s%20still%20a%20debate%20whether%20%E2%80%9Ccoronnials%E2%80%9D%20include%20babies%20born%20during%20the%20pandemic.%20If%20they%E2%80%99re%20conceived%20prior%20to%20quarantine,%20do%20they%20still%20count?%20Do%20we%20really%20want%20to%20ask%20people%20when%20they%20were%20conceived?%20We%20might%20as%20well%20include%20all%20the%20babies%20born%20in%202020%20in%20the%20%E2%80%9Ccoronnials%E2%80%9D%20generation%20since%20some%20are%20practically%20born%20wearing%20face%20shields.%20[esquiremag.ph,%2017%20April%202020])*** - noun [C]
(UK /kəˈrəʊ.ni.əl/ US /kəˈroʊ.ni.əl/)

> someone who was born around the time of the covid-19 pandemic

Apparently, only the earliest post about the term “coronnial” was made by the Urban Dictionary on March 14th:

***[Coronnials](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=coronnials)***

> The babies conceived during the “Home Quarantine” practice linked to COVID19. The first wave of Coronnials will be born 9 months after the “Social Distancing” movement has taken hold in your community.

Both sources seem to refer to a very recent usage, possibly from newspapers or online sites, in which the term was actually coined.

Given the term refers to very recent events, can anyone provide  details about where the term was first used and by whom ?

Comment: Next thing you know, there'll be arguments about whether it shouldn't be _coronial_ with a single N; then there'll be neocoronialism to contend with.

Comment: @JohnLawler - you are right. Probably the double n is on imitation of millennial.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - interesting, but I don’t think it is the term with the connotation and the context given  by the sources cited in my question.

Comment: At this point, this is, at best, somebody's **proposal** that a new word be introduced into the language. It takes more than a couple of months for anybody to be able to judge whether such a proposal is accepted by a sufficient number of speakers to be worthy of being recognised as a part of the language.